# How to validate a data field for A-Z, 0-9 and "*" in SQL Windows?

Tags: validation, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I'm trying to define the input mask for a field in SQL Windows. I now that setting "AAA" would make the field accept anything from A to Z; "999" would make it accept any number. But how do I make it able to accept the "*" char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. At least according to the SQLwindows 2.1 documentation input masks only support numbers and alphabetic characters.
Have you considered creating your own class? Intercepting the SAM_AnyKey-message and checking the characters against your mask should do the trick.